# Creating an app shortcut in Windows 7 XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, shortcut, application

I have a VERY old legacy app that I've managed to move from machine to machine; the installer for it doesn't actually work under newer versions of Windows, but I was able to track down the registry changes and DLL registrations necessary to make it work.  I'm able to create a desktop icon in my XP mode environment, and the program works... but I'd like to add an icon to the Windows 7 menu, and run the program in semi-native mode.

For example, the icon for Microsoft Security Essentials in XP mode has the following target:
%SystemRoot%\system32\rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\VMCPropertyHandler.dll,LaunchVMSal "Windows XP Mode" "||232f633" "Microsoft Security Essentials"

Now, the only part of that that seems to be "magic" is "||232f633" - does anyone have any idea where that comes from, or how to identify the correct equivalent for an arbitrary program?  I gather that, had the program been installed normally through a .msi file (or WISE, or NSIS, or what have you), this id would have been generated automagically...

Thanks for any insights!
(yes, I am cross-posting at SuperUser - I have a hunch this will find an answer faster here, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to open the Windows XP VM, create the shortcut then copy it to the All Users Profile inside the VM

[Reference](http://msmvps.com/blogs/russel/archive/2009/05/12/auto-publish-with-vpc7.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't work (sure, the shortcut inside the VM works, but it doesn't get added to the Win7 menu.)  This is what I had already tried before I posted the question.

Turns out the actual answer is quite simple: go to Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu (inside the VM) and run the New Shortcut wizard from there.  Mischief managed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu (inside the VM) and run the New Shortcut wizard from there.